# Endogeneity in Logistic Regression

Tags: endogeneity

I am currently working on a logistic regression, where innovation is my independent variable and correlation is my dependent variable. I have some other independent variables and interaction terms but this is my main effect.

How do I test for endogeneity? And is there a syntax in R?

Thanks you a lot in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Logistic regression needs a binary dependent variable, but you say dependent is *correlation*. Please clarify!